# Twig : default filter and bool

Tags: symfony, twig

With `default` filter ([Documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/default.html)), I don't understand this case :

```
{% set ico_only = false %}
{{ dump(ico_only) }} // false
{{ dump(ico_only|default(true)) }} // true
```

Why second dump return true ? `ico_only` is already defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good question.

But in the documentation, it says;`value if the value is undefined or empty` so false is considered as empty.

See this:
https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/769